# ZURB Foundation rendering problems on Chrome for Windows

Tags: html, rendering, zurb-foundation

I am having a strange problem with an app developed using Foundation Framework. 
It seems that there are huge rendering problems, especially during/after scrolling. It may happen that images do not scroll together with the rest of the elements, but they remain static (as if they had fixed position with z-index -1), therefore messing with the other elements.

The issue happens only with Chrome for Windows (tested versions from 35 to 41). While on the latest Chrome (42), released yesterday, the issue is not happening.

It doesn't seem to be a known issue, but I have checked my code and everything looks perfectly fine. After all it works in every other browser perfectly, EVEN ON CHROME FOR MAC!

[This](https://www.dropbox.com/s/d4ot9y7stikrw65/Screenshot%202015-04-23%2014.35.49.png?dl=0) is a screenshot of how the application should look. 
Here are some of the rendering problem happening on Chrome for Windows after/during scrolling the page: [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/afcwxuj7sy5p5pk/Screenshot%202015-04-23%2013.57.27.png?dl=0), [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ebphrrlew394yv2/Screenshot%202015-04-23%2013.55.48.png?dl=0)

Any help on where this might come from, is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Removing the height 100% from 'html' and 'body' solved the problem.